# Nested Immutable js print size

Tags: javascript, arrays, list, immutable.js

I have immutable 
[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ATK78.png)

I want to check the size of the list. I did below

```
console.log(filterLevel1.get('filterOptions').length);
```

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

```
console.log(filterLevel1.get('filterOptions').size);
```

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'size' of undefined

Why?

Comment: have you tried this console.log(filterLevel1.filterOptions.length);

Comment: tried it return undefined error as well

Comment: How did you do the console log from the image? Using `.toJS()`? If not, then this is not an Immutable.js structure. The compiler is obviously right, your `filterLevel1` does not have a `filterOptions` property.

Post the entire code snippet of how you’ve created this structure if you want a better answer.

Comment: Yes using .toJS() and yes im sure its immutable js structure. But once i did filterLevel1.get('filterOptions').toJS(), this doesn't work. From the image itself you know filterLevel1 have filterOptions object then why are you questioning

Comment: But how did you create your immutable object? Using deep or shallow conversion? E.g. `fromJS(yourData)` or `Map(yourData)`? If you used `Map()` to construct your data then the sub-data is not converted deeply. To access it you would have to use plain JS notation. e.g. `data.get('filterLevel1').filterOptions.length`